# access right to parse an XML in java

Tags: java, file, parsing, permissions

hello i have to execute this command:

```
    docRules = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
.newDocumentBuilder().parse( new File(IeplcDeployRules.clx));
```

When i try to create a parser i get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /.../IeplcDeployRules.clx (Permission denied)
```

if i try manually to  read the file it works but i cannot write in it because following are the permission.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 ieplcop ieplcdev  3424 Aug 11 17:16 IeplcDeployRules.clx
```

I do not want to change the permission since the file NEED only to be read from my Java application. I suppose there shold be therefore a way to specify that the file should be opened in read only mode.

I look the possible paramenter of File() parse() and .newDocumentBuilder() but none of them let me specify that the operation is read only!!

Any idea about how to procede?

Cheers,
Ste

Comment: Can you please fix the code snippet please? It might be important.

Comment: what kind of application is this happening in? are you using tomcat?

Comment: i do not know what is the snippet. sorry.

Comment: it's not tomecat... it's a normal java application running under linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know what the `DocumentBuilder` does internally, I would have to read its source. But you can use a different `InputSource` instead of a `File`, so that you have full control. For example a [FileReader](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html).

```
documentBuilder.parse(new InputSource(new FileReader(...));
```

Comment: I tryed already but parse cannot to be applied to such an object! File or inputSource are accepted only!

Comment: Yeah, but an InputSource is just a wrapper... I added an example

Answer (score 0):

You should pass an `InputStream` to the `parse` method instead of a `File`.

For example:

```
docRules = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder().parse( new FileInputStream(new File("IeplcDeployRules.clx")));
```