# Documentbuilder.parse returns error permission denied

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to parse xml in java, with following code

```
File fXmlFile = new File(DAL_DB_ALARM_MOVED_XML);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

The code above throws an exception `Permission Denied` while parse() is being called. Can anybody help me here ???

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have read permission issue on the file system? 
Please verify this, and also print the stracktrace.

Comment: This seems more apt like a comment rather than an answer :)

Comment: I have the full permissions drwxrwxr-x 11 database ccmbase 4096 Oct 31 12:13 db

Comment: /usr/local/cm/db/moved_cuc_alarm_file.xml(Permission denied)
javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:208)
org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLVersionDetector.determineDocVersion(Unknown Source)
org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)

Comment: sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:79)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)

Comment: Is it IOException?  The permission you are showing here is only for the directory.  Check the permission of the XML file too.

Comment: The xml permission is 660 , is that what is really bothering me ??? I would like understand logic behind parsing , what does it really do ?

Comment: Please perform ls -la on the file and specify if the program that runs the application is run from a user who is owner of the XML file, or a member in a group that has R/W permissions. 660 means that both the user and the group he is a member of have R/W access. You may consider to use chown to change ownership

Comment: Thanks all , it came to be a file permission issue :-) .

Answer (score 0):

Try what is suggested here.

[access right to parse an XML in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7029007/access-right-to-parse-an-xml-in-java)

Make sure you have the read permission and do not keep the file open (just a try).

Comment: I tried using InputStream , still the same error Encountered error while xml parsing./usr/local/cm/db/moved_cuc_alarm_file.xml (Permission denied)
java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
com.cisco.unity.srm.dal.DbMonitor$CheckAlarmsTask.run(DbMonitor.java:228)
com.cisco.unity.srm.dal.DbMonitor.access$100(DbMonitor.java:36)
com.cisco.unity.srm.dal.DbMonitor.checkAlarms(DbMonitor.java:179)
com.cisco.unity.srm.dal.DAL.monitorAlarms(DAL.java:515)
java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)